# How should I initialize a BerkeleyDB key-data pair for getting?

Tags: compiler-warnings, berkeley-db, database-cursor

I'm working out some kinks in an unmaintained codebase which uses the BerkeleyDB library (via its C++ API). Specifically, I'm seeing the following code:

```
Dbt dkey, ddata;

memset(&dkey, 0, sizeof(dkey));
memset(&ddata, 0, sizeof(ddata));

_storage_key_cursor->get( &dkey, &ddata, DB_NEXT );

if ( dkey.get_data() == NULL ) {
  // etc. etc.
}
```

Now, the Dbt class is forward-declared in my `/usr/include/db_cxx.h`, meaning it's not known - at least by the compiler - to be initializable like that. And indeed, I get:

```
../src/AM/WSMV.cpp: In member function ‘BDBPage* WSMV::getNextSKPage()’:
../src/AM/WSMV.cpp:126:32: warning: ‘void* memset(void*, int, size_t)’ clearing an object of type ‘class Dbt’ with no trivial copy-assignment; use assignment or value-initialization instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
   memset(&dkey, 0, sizeof(dkey));
```

and the same for `ddata`.

However, it seems this memset'ing to 0 is somewhat customary: The [BerkeleyDB Reference Guide](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs276a/projects/docs/berkeleydb/reftoc.html) does so in [this example](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs276a/projects/docs/berkeleydb/ref/am/curget.html).

So, what should I do?

- Suppress/ignore the warning?
- Explicitly initialize or construct in some other way?
- Not initialize at all, leaving it up to the default initialization?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess:

class Dbt inherits - privately - from the (C API) DBT type, which is a typedef for `struct __db_dbt`. Its definition is:

```
struct __db_dbt {
        void *     data;
        u_int32_t  size;
        u_int32_t  ulen;
        u_int32_t  dlen;
        u_int32_t  doff;
        void *     app_data;
        u_int32_t  flags;
};
```

with a flags value of 0 meaning no flags are set. This at least means that the `memset()` is not immediately and obviously harmful. I could reinterpret-cast as a `struct __db_dbt` and set some fields manually, but I'm not sure which ones to set. Plus - I'm not sure that the ones which don't have API functions can safely be set to 0 .